# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/logswitch/switch.xml: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, flutter

My flutter application runs fine but after running application when I touch my phone screen it display the above error.

here is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
    package="com.ruhul.appname">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:label="TheCitizen"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"> .....
```

I don't add any code in native java or swift. What's wrong with my code??

Comment: I see no error. Can you put it in your post to begin with?

Comment: Further it is unclear what touching a phone screen has to do with your app.

Comment: W/System.err( 8433): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/logswitch/switch.xml: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: O how difficult. `Can you put it in your post to begin with?` In your post at the beginning. Not after the dish in a comment. Sigh..

Comment: @blackapps yes, after run my app in phone when i press a TextFormField or any where it will display this error